# How could one create a expiring annotation using swifts MapKit and firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, mapkit, firebase-realtime-database

Hello and thanks for your time. If you stumble upon this I'm having a bit of issue and it requires some knowledge with Firebase / Swift and Swift's mapkit. So what I'm trying to do is create an expiring annotation. A user puts a pin on a map and after some amount of time (say 3 hours) the annotation disappears.

I've read about one thing where you can use NSTImer, but the issue is that if the phone is asleep or powered off it might have issues with NSTimer. Instead, I was thinking of using Firebase to save the annotation and use the time stamp to show when the point should expire. I saw another stack overflow post regarding this which involved if / else statements to check when a certain time has passed and to bring remove the data after the time.

The post never explained how to actually do that, and also I'm not actually sure how to create an observer that will easily check if a certain time has passed based on the timestamp. If anyone could create some code or point me in the right direction, would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: You can also use a user settings file to store when annotation was created and then check if time expired - you will delete it and don't show on the map

Comment: You can store your annotations with creation time recorded in Firebase. Then when you're going to show all annotations on map. Just check the timestamp to determine it is going to show or not.

Comment: Also, you can check on [NSTimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate:)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Both interesting solutions. So for the timestamp suggested by Wei Jay, could you provide what you're proposing in code? I understand what you are saying but don't know how to do said thing. Thanks,